# 'block/plugin' show a selected node. When editing the available nodes are filtered by type (or views)

Tags: 7, panels

There is a way to put a 'block/plugin' in a panel which, when edited by an admin, would have a list (using views if possible) of nodes to choose?

The idea is to place this 'block/plugin' in a pane of 'services', for example, and allow the admin to easily change the viewed 'node of type services' in a easy list. Something like [node_pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_pane), but not exactly the same.

With this I can say something like 'here will be a highlighted news, there will be 3 highlighted services' and so on.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, isn't exactly what I was looking for, but does the job.
I created a content "News Holder", then added a field using entity reference and multiple selects. This field I set to have the number of "News Content" that I want and them a just need to place this content (used panels in this case).
This field can be configured to show a list (select list) of entities that the entity reference can reference.

So, using this way the user with admin privileges viewing the page can click the cog icon and edit, to edit this node. In the edit page he have direct access to the selects of the news content. It's direct and easy to use.

If someone still manage to do something similar or better, I would love to read =)